# Dynamic Graph Generator

Tags: graph, generator

I need to plot points of a line graph dynamically..(same like an oscilloscope in ecg).. can someone please suggest some tool that contains such a feature!!..

Comment: You have to tell us what environment (mac, pc, etc.) and what toolset you're already using for anyone to be able to help.  Without that, I'd suggest pen and paper.

Comment: sorry!! windows or linux any one will work :).. we are using xgraph but its giving static graphs.. I want to plot point by point kinda animation..

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) with python.You might also use an script for [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).

What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This would be pretty easy with the paths in WPF.  Of course, just about any language will let you draw a line on the screen pretty quickly.

What is the input data?  Is it from a file, a piece of hardware, something else?